# Why apps asks permission without writing it in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have an app in which the manifest have only following lines in permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

But while installing the app the play store shows following permissions

**Identity**
Uses one or more of: accounts on the device, profile data
**Location**
Uses the device's location
**Photos/Media/Files**
Uses one or more of: files on the device such as images, videos, or audio, the device's external storage

Since I am not asking for user location neither I am using it, why play store is showing this ?

**Edit:how to fix**

The link on accepted answer and [this google page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) helped me solve the issue. Basically play-services used location so I just replaced them with service-plus and service-ads which solved the issue. Hope this will help some other developers.

Specifically
replace `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'`

with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'
```

Comment: becuase of used libraries ...

Comment: It looks weird, maybe are you using some thid party library who required this permissions ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Since I am not asking for user location neither I am using it, why play store is showing this ?

It's shows what your app requires, even you did not put it explicitly in your Manifest file. In fact the final Manifest is a result of merge of your `AndroidManifest.xml` and all the manifests your dependencies (these usually referenced via gradle's `compile ...`) provide.

If you wonder which dependency contributes to your final permission requirements, you can check manifest merger report file in `<PROJECT>/app/build/outputs/logs` folder and look for `uses-permission#<PERMISSION_YOU_LOOK_FOR>`, i.e.:

```
uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:11:5
MERGED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0:22:5
```

Further reads:

- official documentation chapter: [Merge Multiple Manifest Files](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html)
- blog post on the subject: [Hey, Where Did These Permissions Come From?](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html)